# Jump not stopping XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm having a problem with my jump in XNA.
The character slightly jumps but I can still go up the screen before coming back down.  This give the effect that its not a jump also i had move left, right working and they do not work unless the player is in the air.
What I want to happen is a mario type jump where the user presses up and can move left or right until the player falls.

Can someone help me with this.

Here is my code: (Which is in the update of the player)

```
public void handleInput(GameTime gameTime)
{
    this.Transform.MoveIncrement = Vector2.Zero;
    float timeBetweenUpdates = 0.25f * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

    if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    {
        this.Transform.MoveIncrement += -this.Transform.Look;
        this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
    }
    else if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    {
        this.Transform.MoveIncrement += this.Transform.Look;
        this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
    }
    if (game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(Keys.Up))
    {
       // this.Transform.MoveIncrement = -Vector2.UnitY * timeBetweenUpdates;
        this.Transform.moveBy(-Vector2.UnitY);
        this.Transform.IsMoved = true;
        this.hasJumped = true;
    }
    else if(timeBetweenUpdates > 450)
    {
        hasJumped = true;
    }
    else if (hasJumped == true)
    {
        this.Transform.MoveIncrement = Vector2.UnitY * timeBetweenUpdates;
        this.Transform.IsMoved= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Proofread your post; it's hard to read.  I can't tell whether or not you want your character to be able to move when he jumps.

Comment: I'm afraid that that update doesn't help much.  It appears as though your problem is that your character goes up and then down when you jump.  Isn't that what's supposed to happen?

Comment: edited the post there :)

Comment: Well technically yes but when im in the air i can jump again i cant figure out how to limit the jump so that when it goes up by so much height it comes back down.

Comment: You would be better served using physics to handle the player velocity in 2 directions

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way of telling if your player is on the ground?  if you do, than just incorporate that into your `if` statement.

```
// insert your own way of telling whether or not the player is jumping 
//or if he is on the ground
bool playerIsOnGround = this.YPosition = 0;

if ( isPlayerOnGround && game.KeyboardManager.isKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{
```

Comment: no the only thing i have is hasjumped which i ahould tell when to come back down....